# increment date based on a refence date

Tags: sas

Hi I have a data with dates which has to be incremented to a value stored in another variable.

```
Sno     Date1     Date2
1     20120201  20130101
1     20120201  20130101
2     20030812  20030908
2     20030812  20030908
3     20110402  20110602
3     20110402  20110602
```

No I have to increment date1 longitudinally till (date2 - 20days). 
How can I use this in loop

if I use like

```
do i=a to b-20; 
increment=intnx('day',date1,i);
end;
```

then it takes the SAS number of days and goes beyond the date2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data table;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input sno date1 :anydtdte. date2 :anydtdte.;
format date1 date2 date.;
datalines;
1|20120201|20130101
1|20120201|20130101
2|20030812|20030908
2|20030812|20030908
3|20110402|20110602
3|20110402|20110602
;
run;

data result;
set table;
do increment=date1 to date2-20;
  output;
end;
format increment date.;
run;
```

assuming `date1` and `date2` are stored as characters

Comment: This is a correct answer code-wise, but good answers should include an explanation outside of code of how they work (teach a man to fish, not give him fish).

Comment: @Joe you're right. However, his question was unclear and this answers what I think he needs. If this is not what he needs or he indeed does not understand, I'm happy to further explain. That said, the part of the code which answers is an extremely simple piece of code that, I think, anyone with _some_ knowledge of SAS should understand without a need for explanation. If the asker has none, this is not the place to learn SAS.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is the standard Stack Overflow chooses to hold answers to (read [answer] for more information).  An answer that is just code is not a good answer.  If the question is unclear, than ask for clarification rather than answering.